# Maximum number of concurrent requests a webserver can serve assuming average service time to be known

Tags: performance, webserver

Is it logical to say: "If average service time for a request is X and affordable waiting time for the requests is Y then maximum number of concurrent requests to serve would be Y / X" ?

I think what I'm asking is that if there're any hidden factors that I'm not taking into account!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking specifically about webservers, then no, your formula doesn't work, because webservers are designed to handle multiple, simultaneous requests, using [forking or threading](http://www.zerigo.com/article/apache_multi-threaded_vs_multi-process_pre-forked/).

This turns the formula into something far harder to quantify - in my experience, web servers can handle LOTS (i.e. hundreds or thousands) of concurrent requests which consume little or no time, but tend to reduce that concurrency quite dramatically as the requests consume more time.

That means that "average service time" isn't massively useful - it can hide wide variations, and it's actually the outliers that affect you the most.

Answer (score 3):

Broadly yes, but your service provider (webserver in your case) is capable of handling more than one request in parallel, so you should take that into account. I assume you measured end to end service time and havent already averaged it by number of parallel streams. One other thing you didnt and cannot realistically measure is the delay to/from your website.

What you are heading towards is the Erlang unit (not the language using the same name) which is used to described how much load a system can take. Erlangs are unitless (it is just a number) and originated from old school telephony, POTS, where it was used to describe how many wires were needed to handle X calls per time period with low blocking probability. Beyond erlang is engset which is used more for high capacity systems, such as mobile systems.

It also gets used for expensive consultant reports into realtime computer systems and databases to describe the point at which performance degradation is likely to occur.  Wikipedia has an article on this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(unit) and the book 'Fixed and mobile telecommunications, network systems and services' has a good chapter on performance analysis.

While aimed at telephone systems, just replace with word webserver and it behaves the same. A webserver is the same concept, load is offered that arrives at random intervals to a system with finite parallel capacity. In your case, you can probably calculate total load with load tools easier than parallel capacity and then back calculate the formulas. This is widely done to gain a level of confidence in overall system models.

Erlang/engsetformulas are really useful when you have a randomly arriving load over parallel stream (ie web requests) and a service time that can only be averaged or estimated (ie it varies in real life). You can then calculate the blocking probability, which is the probability a new request will need to wait while current requests are serviced, and how long it will wait. It also helps analyse whether you need to handle more requests in parallel, or make each faster (#lines and holding time in erlang speak)

You will probably look into queuing systems analysis next, as a soon as requests block (queue), the models change slightly.

Answer (score 1):

many factors are not taken into account

- memory limits
- data locking constraints such as people wanting to update the same data
- application latency
- caching mechanisms
- different users will have different tasks on the site and put different loads

That said, one easy way to get a rough estimate is with apache ab tool (apache benchmark)

Example, get 1000 times the homepage with 100 requests at a time:

```
  ab -c 100 -n 1000 http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: I believe the factors you have mentioned are all included in my "average service time", aren't they?

Comment: for the most part yes but not necessarily - some constraints only kick in if you have enough concurrent users. as an example, if you have one request per minute - database will not necessarily lock - if you have multiple at the same time, it will hang. Other factors that might not be an issue at small usage scenario may appear as well. That said, it is always good to start with a rough estimate

Comment: Your point's taken and I really appreciate it, but my question is more of a logical discussion than a practical one. Just think of my *average service time* as the actual true one (the one calculated in field), now try to think of any extra factors that might play a role. How about now?

Comment: lol my answer is still the same - you do get a rough estimate but not a definite answer when it comes to actual scaling. among others factors are concurrency - multiple threads / multiple processors would play a role but also network bandwidth, data locking, how well your application plays with additional servers/load balancing, etc... tons of factors may come to play.